# How do I correct this UNIX command for copying files into a directory?

Tags: bash, unix, while-loop, cp

I have the following command that does not work

```
while read line; do ls $line | head -10 | cp xargs dest_folder; done < my_file.txt
```

The objective is that I have a file named my_file.txt that contains the name of a folder on every line. I want to copy 10 files from each of the directories mentioned on every line of this file into a dest_folder.

How can I correct the above command?

Comment: `copy 10 files` on what basis? by creation time or by modification time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cand achive this with the following bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# first argument is the filename which contains ton each line a name of a folder
# teh second argument is the destination folder

while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
    filesToCopy=($(ls $line |head -n 10))
    for i in "${filesToCopy[@]}"
    do
        :
        cp $line/$i $2
    done

done < "$1"
```

**Usage:**

```
chmod +x your_bash_script
./your_bash_script my_file.txt dest_folder
```

**Note:**

The folder names inside the file should be absolute paths.

Comment: Giving this a try now. Thanks.

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks.

Comment: Glad i could help!

Comment: Can you give me a reference where I can learn such advanced bash scripting please?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `xargs` with the `-I` option:

```
while read line; do ls $line | head -10 | xargs -I % cp % dest_folder; done
```

Answer (score 1):

In general, you [should not use the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) programmatically. Use a second loop to iterate over the files in each directory.

```
while IFS= read -r directory; do
    count=0
    for f in "$directory"/*; do
        (( count++ < 10 )) || break
        cp -- "$f" "$dest_folder"
    done
done < my_file.txt
```

This will work for *any* legal file name found in the directory.